# Pinging multiple IP addresses without using muti-threading

Tags: java

I am developing a system for pinging IP addresses and generating reports on failures and some other stats in java. For pinging multiple IP addresses, i want all IP addresses pinging at once. Using multi-threading seems impossible because i have just one method with the IP address and text area for display as parameters. I have this method in a for loop, where the parameters are assigned on every iteration.

```
public Runnable runSystemCommand(String command ,JTextArea replyView ) throws FileNotFoundException, 
        IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    return new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            PingDB db = new PingDB();
            try {
                db.openConnection();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ping_IP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
           try{
               address = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
               status = address.isReachable(100000);

               //for (String ipAddress : ips){
               if (status){
                   Timestamp timeIn = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                   replyView.setText(replyView.getText()+ System.getProperty("line.separator")
                           +"Server reached at "+ timeIn);

               }else{
                   Timestamp tOut = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                  replyView.setText(replyView.getText()+ System.getProperty("line.separator")+
                          "Server timed out at "+tOut);

               }
               try {
                   p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

                   }catch (IOException ex) {
                   Logger.getLogger(ping_IP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               }

                Scanner S = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
                while (S.hasNextLine()) {
                    final String newText = S.nextLine();

                    if (newText.startsWith("Reply from ")||newText.startsWith("64 bytes of data")){

                        pingCount++;
                        //String sttm = "Insert into pingstatus Values ("+pingCount+",);";
                    }else{

                        timeOuts++;

                    }
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                        public void run() {
                           //System.out.println(newText);
                           replyView.setText(replyView.getText()
                                    + System.getProperty("line.separator")
                                    + newText);
                        }
                    });

                }

           }catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace(); 

                               }
        }          
    };
}
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);


private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //jButton is used to initiate the ping
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){ 
            try {
                if (ips.size() == 1){

                    newPing.executor.execute(newPing.runSystemCommand("ping "+ips.get(0)+" -t",inputArea)); 

                }else{
                  //this is where the method above is called.  

                    for (String ip : ips) {
                        System.out.println(ip);
                        MultiView newView = new MultiView();
                        newView.setTitle("Pinging "+ip);
                        newView.setVisible(true);

                       newPing.executor.execute(newPing.runSystemCommand("ping "+ ip+" -t",newView.mView));

                    }
                }    
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
   });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code so far? You cannot do it without multithreading as far as I can think of it!

Comment: you should create a separate object for every ping with its special parameters, let say a class that implements Runnable and then sent all one of the object to its own thread, wait for all to finish, and display the result however you want

Comment: Multithreading *is* of course possible. It's not just threads, it's also locks, queues and events which you should learn how to use.

Answer (score 2):

In my view your argument against multi-threading is invalid:

1. your requirement is to ping all IP addresses at once, which is just another phrase for "concurrently"
2. [InetAddress.isReachable()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29) and invoking and parsing the output of an external command are of blocking nature
3. your code can be refactored so multi-threading is easier to implement

Use [SwingWorkers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to separate the background work (the pinging) from updating the GUI. Other advantages are ([see the tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)):

- Provide a result to calling Thread
- Cancellation, discovering if background task has finished or been cancelled
- update GUI after background task finished ([see SwingWorker.done()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done--))
- intermediate results to update GUI in EDT ([see SwingWorker.process(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#process-java.util.List-))
- background task can define bound properties which trigger events, causing event-handling methods to be invoked on EDT

Your current code updates components from a thread which is not the EDT which violates Swings Concurrency rules, with swing workers you solve this issue almost for free (without using `EventQueue.invokeLater(...)` like you did in some cases.

Some advice at the end:

- you can use executors and thread pools in background tasks, too
- refactor your codebase to have classes with a single responsibility (handling external programs output, pinging, ...)
- `InetAddress.isReachable(...)` does alot of the work you do with your external ping utility, is it worth removing one?

  > A typical implementation will use ICMP ECHO REQUESTs if the privilege
  >   can be obtained, otherwise it will try to establish a TCP connection
  >   on port 7 (Echo) of the destination host.